# fancy tooltips in Swing

Tags: swing, jtable, tooltip, jtextarea

I have a JTable that I would like to display a fancy tooltip (basically a JTextArea) for particular cells in a column. I am using a custom cell renderer, so it would be easy if I could figure out how to popup a window when I hover over the cell renderer's component.

Are there any examples of how to do this?

Comment: This may be of some use http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/SwingTableColumnToolTipSample.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [use HTML in tooltips](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Htmltooltips.htm), if you use the `<html>` and `</html>` tags around the content.

Use HTML to format the tooltip. Using colored (`<font>`) and multi-line (`<br>`) tooltips is now easy.

---

Creating and overwriting the default `JToolTip` is a bit harder. Every component has a `JToolTip` instance and you can retrieve this one with `JComponent.createToolTip()`. To create a custom tooltip, extend the [cell renderer](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.table/CustRend.html) and override it's `createToolTip` to implement your custom functionality (return a custom extended version of `JToolTip`).

Comment: cool, I'll try the HTML approach. w/r/t createToolTip: it shouldn't be on the JTable, it should be on the component returned by the TableCellRenderer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I totally am clear on what sort of customizations specifically you're hoping to do, so I'll be general here.

There is a class, [UIManager](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html), that controls the look and feel of components, including the swing ToolTip class. The simple way to make an easy change is to call a method in UIManager to set properties for the tooltips. Doing this you could do things like use BorderFactory to add a decorative border, or change the background color, etc.

Here are some examples of changing some of these properties:

```
UIManager.put("ToolTip.background", new ColorUIResource(255, 247, 200)); // The color is #fff7c8.
Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(76,79,83)); // The color is #4c4f53.
UIManager.put("ToolTip.border", border);
ToolTipManager.sharedInstance().setDismissDelay(15000);// 15 seconds
```

If you want to change a whole bunch of things about their look and feel, it is better to extend your current look and feel with a class implementing custom tooltip look and feel. A [full example](http://blogs.oracle.com/moonocean/entry/change_properties_of_java_tooltip) of this can be found in this blog post by a former Sun developer.

You might also have a look at this Stack Overflow question on [how to set the insets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192440/how-can-i-set-the-insets-of-a-tooltip-java) on a tooltip.